# How to read parquet files into array of python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, parquet

Is there a way to convert parquet files into an array of python dictionaries where the keys are the columns?

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
```

Does that library natively support that feature?

Comment: Might have luck with : `pq.read_table("example.parquet").to_pylist()`

Comment: nah no dice: `pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Reading lists of structs from Parquet files not yet supported: key_value: list<key_value: struct<key: string not null, value: string> not null> not null`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

- [to_pydict](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.to_pydict) to get a dictionary of array (one array per column)
- [to_pylist](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.to_pylist) to get an array of dictionary (one dictionary per row)

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.Series([1, 2, 3], name='col1'), 
        pd.Series(["abc", "def", "ghi"], name='col2')
    ],
    axis=1
)
df.to_parquet('df.parquet')
pq.read_table('df.parquet').to_pydict()
>>> {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']}
pq.read_table('df.parquet').to_pylist()
>>> [{'col1': 1, 'col2': 'abc'},
 {'col1': 2, 'col2': 'def'},
 {'col1': 3, 'col2': 'ghi'}]
```

Comment: The original question asked whether the library could natively produces an array of Python dictionaries. Your example produces a single dictionary. The asker might be happy with this (since they could take care of producing and managing an array in their own code), but I wasn't sure, so I left a comment about it on the original question.

Comment: @Alan thanks, I've updated the response accordingly.